# Is Cursed Child canon to the original story?

Tags: harry-potter, canon, the-cursed-child

From what I am hearing the stage-play called *The Cursed Child* is based on the characters from the *Harry Potter* series. It is set 19 years from the end of Deathly Hallows (i.e. When Harry's children are starting their time at Hogwarts).

I have also seen the J.K. Rowling has had at least some involvement and been on the set and a part of rehearsals, etc.

My question is has there been a statement given relating to the canon of the stage play to original series? If so, would any conflicting information be considered a retcon?

Related: [Are J.K. Rowling interviews Harry Potter canon? What happens to canon if there's a discrepancy with the book?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10491/are-j-k-rowling-interviews-harry-potter-canon-what-happens-to-canon-if-theres) - but not dupe because this asking about in-universe information.

Comment: @Valorum The Gold Badge strikes again! I almost ended up knowing this was going to happen.....

Comment: Don't ask dupes and you won't get them closed :-)

Comment: @Valorum Actually I am okay with dupe getting closed, even if I ask them... I think this can help since CC is a new work and the tags and title may aid search results

Comment: In this instance, this question is actually pretty useful, even though it's a dupe. It's very similar to my own [What is the canonicity of the new “Lego Star Wars: Droid Tales” TV show?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117442/what-is-the-canonicity-of-the-new-lego-star-wars-droid-tales-tv-show/117443#117443) in that it adds extra info without actually being distinguished.

Comment: @Valorum - Funny enough, all the answers in the linked question clearly say that HP canon doesn't exist. This answer thinks that it does.

Comment: @ibid - JKR seems to think it does; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/136123/what-has-j-k-rowling-said-is-canon

Comment: @Valorum - The general practice on SFF has been to use a canon set based off of  the works written by Rowling, not based off the one or two works she said were canon.

Comment: @ibid - I certainly don't disagree with that sentiment. That being said, she's also written for things that are far enough away from the main canon (wizarding cards, various intros for the Wonderbook game, her now-deleted website, etc etc) to make the picture far murkier than it first appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

I found my own answer while doing a bit of research... Answer is in bold below.

[From Pottermore:](https://www.pottermore.com/news/ww-publishing-cursed-child-script-book-announcement)

> Readers and moviegoers last saw Harry waving off his children at Platform Nine and Three-Quarters, 19 years after the Battle of Hogwarts, in the epilogue to Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows. Harry Potter and the Cursed Child picks up after that moment and is staged in two parts, due to the ‘epic nature of the story’.
>
> The play opens in London’s West End this summer, based on an original new story by J.K. Rowling, Jack Thorne and John Tiffany. **It is officially the eighth story in Harry Potter canon and a new play by Jack Thorne.**

In addition there was a [Tweet by J.K. Rowling](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/615498601809211393) directly addressing the issue:

> The story of #CursedChild should be considered canon, though. @jackthorne, John Tiffany (the director) and I developed it together.

Comment: Of course, as demonstrated by answers to the other question, neither JKR, Pottermore, or WB has any official canon policy, so theses statements are practically wrothless.